# Allowing a nonuser to view an original size picture (not just thumbnail)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm trying to allow nonregistered visitors the ability to access original sized photos on my site that I developed based off the OMRails tutorial. Right now, if a user clicks a pin, they are prompted to sign in to the website. Ideally, I want a nonregistered visitor to be able to visit the same pin page that displays the original size picture as any registered user.

The site is http://community.whatyoutheat.com and the source code can be found at GitHub at https://github.com/harrisongill/whatyoutheat. I tried using the search but was not sure what to call this and ended up mostly with posts about using rails to change image size, something I already know. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
before_filter :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]
```

in your `PinsController`